# Is it $G \lesssim RG$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $G:=\{g_1:=1_G,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ be a finite multiplicative group of order $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $R$ be a ring with $1_R$. We will write $RG$ for the group ring of $G$ over $R$.

I am studying some theory for group rings from the book "An Introduction to Group Rings", by Milies and Sehgal and I stuck on the following point.

It says that the map $i:R\longrightarrow RG,\ g\longmapsto i(g):=1_Rg $ is an embedding. Thus, $G \lesssim RG$.

And I tried to prove that. Without any difficulty, $i$ is a group homomorphism, since
$$\forall g,h\in G:\ i(gh)=1_R(gh)=(1_Rg)(1_Rh)=i(g)i(h).$$
Now let's compute the kernel of $i$. It is,
$$\ker i=\{g\in G:\ i(g)=0_{RG}\}=\{g\in G:\ 1_Rg=0_R1_G\}.$$
*Is $0_{RG}=0_R1_G$ and  how can we prove that $\ker i =\{0_G\}$ (and thus $i$ is injective)?*

Moreover we can consider the map $\nu:R\longrightarrow RG,\ r\longmapsto \nu (r):=r 1_G$ and similarly 
$$\ker \nu = \{ r\in R:\ \nu(r)=0_{RG} \}= \{ r\in R:\ r1_G=0_R1_G \}.$$
But here, $r1_G=0_R1_G \iff r=0_R$ and we are done. Right?

*Thank you.*

Comment: Recall, that $RG$ is a free module with $G$ as basis, so $\iota (g)=g$ as formal basis element and therefore not zero. Your second argument is correct.

Comment: You're mixing up two concepts here. This is not a group homomorphism because the multiplicative monoid of the ring is not a group. The image of $G$ is a group, so you can restrict to that and talk about the kernel, but the identity is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by formal basis? And what do we deduce from this fact? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MattSamuel  Thank you for your comment. Okay, $(RG,\cdot)$ is not a group, but just a monoid. But why does the book say that $i: G \longrightarrow RG$ is an embedding and thus we can regard $G$ as a subset of $RG$? What do I confuse precisely?

Comment: By embedding they mean injective homomorphism of monoids. This can't be determined in general by the kernel alone if the monoid is not a group. There's no normal subgroup to homomorphism correspondence for monoids.

Comment: @Chris $i(g)=i(h)$ iff $1\cdot g=1\cdot h$, which implies $g=h$ by the definition of how generators of a free module.  It's clearly a injective (an embedding.) I have a hard time seeing your confusion as well.

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh, so you mean that we have the monoid homomorphism $i:(G,\cdot)\longrightarrow (RG,\cdot)$ and that to see that $i$ is one to one we should use the definition. And that's the reason why the book says "regard as subset" and not "regard as subgroup". Right?

Comment: Right. ${} {} {} {} {} {} {} $

Comment: @rschwieb It is clear now, thank you very much for your time.